# IDE plugin's for developing multithreaded network applications

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, eclipse-plugin, network-programming

I am looking for a plugin that helps developers create multithreaded network applications that works with either Eclipse and/or Netbeans. Should allow for functionality such as:

- Graphical modeling of callbacks
- Configuring executors
- Creating custom SSL factories
- Wizards for creating various filter streams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a framework?  JBoss Netty (http://www.jboss.org/netty/) and Apache MINA (http://mina.apache.org/) are very similar in function and will both facilitate the sorts of things you mention.  As for an IDE plugin, I don't know of anything but doubt the value of such a tool.